# Как настроить IntelliJ IDEA что-бы все параметры были final при авто генерации?

Tags: intellij-idea

Как настроить `IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2` что бы при любой генерации методов и конструкторов все параметры по умолчанию получали модификатор `final`? Если это возможно.

Comment: как вы генерирует методы? зачем вам нужен final везде?